# ffmpeg: `select` filter output frame numbers are off

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to extract certain frames from video, but using this command

```
ffmpeg -i "video-a.mkv" -vf select="eq(n\,100)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts true "a_%06d.jpg"
ffmpeg -i "video-b.mkv" -vf select="eq(n\,100)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts true "b_%06d.jpg"
```

it seems I'm getting inconsistent results. for different videos I get differently named files:

```
a_000103.jpg
b_000101.jpg
```

why is that?

Comment: What happens with `ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -i "video-a.mkv" -vf null,select="eq(n\,100)" -vsync 0 -frame_pts true "a_%06d.jpg"`

Comment: it still produces the same output

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: since it's too long to add it to a post, see https://pastebin.com/Y7Cbpxrh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input in the log file has a delayed video start time. Reset timestamps, to make it independent of that possibility.

```
ffmpeg -i "video-a.mkv" -vf setpts=N/TB,select="eq(n\,100)" -r 1 -vsync 0 -frame_pts true "a_%06d.jpg"
```